# How to Solve DispatcherServlet Class not found Exception

Tags: spring

I am trying to run **Hello world Spring MVC** Program. But I am getting the following errors. I have tried so many times from different website, But I couldn't solve this Problem. So Please can anyone help me to solve this.

> Apr 29, 2018 7:32:12 **PM
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader
>   initWebApplicationContext
>       SEVERE: Context initialization failed
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'helloWorldService' defined in file
>   [/home/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/spring-web-gradle-xml/WEB-INF/classes/com/mkyong/helloworld/service/HelloWorldService.class]:
>   Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is**
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   ch/qos/logback/core/joran/spi/JoranException
>
> INFO: Marking servlet spring as unavailable
>       Apr 29, 2018 7:32:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
>       SEVERE: Servlet /SpringMVC-Hibernate threw load() exception
>       java.lang.**ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet**
>         at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
>         at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:529)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that **[logback](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#configFileProperty)** Jar is in your classpath.

You can go through [this](https://logback.qos.ch/setup.html) manual and configure your project accordingly.

In case you use a build tool, feel free to post your build configuration file here for a more detailed answer.

Comment: I don't have pom.xml, But I have web.xml & servlet.xml